# Pass parameters with special characters in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a script file that can receive some arguments on this way:

```
echo --debug will run the tests but not run the installer. This need to be the first parameter.
echo --testcases=TESTCASES Provide a list of testcases to execute instead of those in App.config. The TESTCASES list commma-separated.
echo --dbkeys=DATABASEKEYS Provide a list of UTDB keys to prepare instead of those in App.config. The DB keys in question must be a subset of those mentioned in App.config. The DATABASEKEYS list should be commma-separated.
```

So for example you can call this file 
`./file.bat --testcases="test1, test2" --dbkeys="db1"`
This part work fine because in the script I have this call:
 `call Test\MidTierLibUT\bin\Release\FleetManagerAPI.MidTierLibUT.exe %* || exit /b -2`
but if I put as first parameter `--debug`, I want to do different things before I call 
`call Test\MidTierLibUT\bin\Release\FleetManagerAPI.MidTierLibUT.exe %* || exit /b -5` and in the `%*` I will like to not have there --debug passing.

So I tried:

```
shift
:start
if [%1] == [] goto done
set args=%args% %~1
shift
goto start

:done
call Test\MidTierLibUT\bin\Debug\FleetManagerAPI.MidTierLibUT.exe %args% || exit /b -5
```

but `%args%` will look like: `--testcases test1 test2` (with no " or = )

someone can help me please?

Comment: 1. Use syntax `if "%~1" == ""`, not the one with the brackets! 2. `set args=%args% %~1` should be changed to `set args=%args% "%~1"` in order to have each argument quoted, thus protecting white-spaces and other special characters. 3. This approach will still fail with weird arguments like `"&"&`, for instance, but such would not make much sense anyway, would they? 4. Why using `call` to run a `.exe` file, although it is not necessary?

Comment: That help @aschipfl thanks. But still not perfect.
if I call `./file.bat --debug --testcases="test1,test2"` what I can see in %args% is `"--testcases" "test1" "test2"` and should be `--testcases="test1,test2"`

Comment: Then call `./file.bat --debug "--testcases=test1,test2"` instead; `--argument` doesn't mean anything in batch, so the entire string is one big parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought a little out the box trying to find the solution and with the ideas of @aschipfl and @SomethingDark I figurate that it was easier to remove that part of the string all together and send the rest :)
So the solution is something like:

```
set args=%*
set args= %args:--debug=%
Test\MidTierLibUT\bin\Debug\FleetManagerAPI.MidTierLibUT.exe %args% || exit /b -5
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nice! let me suggest to change the first and second lines to `set args= %* ` (plus trailing space) and `set "args=%args: --debug = %"`, respectively, so something like `--debug-info` would not be erroneously changed to `-info`, given that only spaces are used as argument separators (not other characters allowed in `cmd` like tab, `,`, `;`, `=`, for instance). In addition, consider to enable [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) after the first line in order to protect special characters...